# Parsing and using the data without NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

In my application I need to get the data from a server and parse it. By googling I found a tutorial about `NSXMLParser` and used it in my project. I just Parsed the data and used the method below in `viewDidLoad` to stop my UI from blocking. I Didn't use `NSURLConnection` anywhere in my Project. But still its working perfectly.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(methodName:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

1.Is it Mandatory to use `NSURLConnection`?

2.If I use `NSURLConnection` Can I write `NSXMLParser` and `NSURLConnection` delegate methods in the same class (I read in a post that it is not a good practice)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it Mandatory to use NSURLConnection?

No. Why would it?

> 2.If i use NSURLConnection Can i write NSXMLParser and NSURLConnection delegate methods in the same class.

Of course you can. I don't see any reason this would be bad practice.